# How do I use php to break an unordered list loop?

Tags: php, list, loops, html-lists, accordion

I'm trying to find a solution in php that will achieve the below examples.

I have multiple UL's and want to automatically break them after the 4th list item (to hide items 5 and up in a collapsible accordion). Each list will have different number of list items, some less than 4, but still apply the break.

Ideally the collapsible accordion doesn't need to exist if less than 4 items, but I can't wrap my head around another method. I am only successfully able to break after 4 items using the $counter++ and echo the break if($counter == 4){}. I still need a solution for lists with less than 4 items.

For example if the list has more than 4 items, it will break and continue the list after:

```
<div class="always-shown-section">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

  <!--------INSERT BREAK HERE-------->
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="collapsible-section">
  <ul>
  <!---CONTINUE REMAINDER OF LIST---->

    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And still add the break if the loop contains less than 4 items:

```
<div class="always-shown-section">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>

  <!--------INSERT BREAK HERE-------->
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="collapsible-section">
  <ul>
  <!--NO ITEMS IN REMAINDER OF LIST-->

  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
To target the UL's with less than 4 items I just added an else if statement with: else if(count($array) < 4) { do something }

Comment: add the loop part of the code

Comment: Just have an if/else that checks the length of the array and then has different styling/output logic for each case

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I found something that works. Will update my original post.